# What is String T(a,b) in C++

Tags: c++

While I learned `C++` I challenged sample problems in which each `1` in stdin will move right in stdout.
In sample answer,`T(4,0)` is defined.
As I am beginner, I couldn't understand what is `T(4,0)`. is this different from normal arrays? Thanks

sample answer

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string S;
  cin >> S;
  string T(4,0);
  T[0]='0';
  T[1]=S[0];
  T[2]=S[1];
  T[3]=S[2];
  cout << T;
}
```

Comment: Don't learn from random websites, they suck. Read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) As well as [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` has several [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). In this case:

```
basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

(You don't provide an argument for `alloc` so the default is used. Don't worry about it.)

This constructor has the following effects:

> 2. Constructs the string with `count` copies of character `ch`. [This constructor is not used for class template argument deduction if the Allocator type that would be deduced does not qualify as an allocator. (since C++17)]

So this creates a `std::string` with `4` characters in it, and each character is `0`, aka `'\0'`, aka null.

Answer (score 2):

Since `T` is a `std::string`, it's the constructor of `std::string`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

In this case, it's the constructor under *2)*:

```
basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

(`alloc` is a default argument and not needed to be supplied by you.)
It creates a string with `count` characters and every character is initialized to `ch`.

In your case, it's a string with 4 characters, all initialized to whatever ascii value `0` has. The `\0` character.